# Adding id column of table to a hstore column postgres

Tags: postgresql, hstore

I am trying to figure out how to store the id column of a table into a hstore column.  That way the id is stored in two places.  Going forward the table will be moved to another database and the current id will need to be preserved.

I have tried:

```
update new_table set hstore_col = hstore_col || hstore("id",id::text) where id = 1
```

This does not work  Any other suggestions adding the id column of a database table to a hstore column it has.

Comment: Double quoted `"id"` is an identifier, use `'id'` instead to specify the string literal: `hstore('id', id::text)`

Comment: @Abelisto can you make that an answer, so he can make the question as answered?

Comment: @EvanCarroll There are already a tons of Q&A about the same issue. However, done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually in SQL double quotes used to specify the identifiers like tables, columns, functions and other DB objects which name contains "non-conventional" characters or have to be case-sensitive. For example it is correct PostgreSQL statement:

```
create table "This is#my...%TABLE" ("And&Field" int);
```

(**It is not recommended to use such names however** because it may cause a lot of problems)

So double quoted literals meanings the DB objects and in the your statement `"id"` meanings the `id` field.

On the other hand to specify the string literal in the standard SQL you have to use single quotes. For example:

```
select 'foo' as "bar field";
```

Here `'foo'` is a text constant and `"bar field"` is a column alias where double quotes is required because of the space character inside it.

According to the above you have to change your statement to

```
update new_table set hstore_col = hstore_col || hstore('id',id::text) where id = 1
```